# Javascript: Trouble taking user input and running it in another function

Tags: javascript, html

New to the JS world and I have a few questions. I'm trying to take the user's input and run it through another function but seem to be getting stuck. When I accept the user input using window prompt, the code works correctly.

```js
function lookup(address, callback) {
  var electionId;
  var address = prompt("Enter your address: ");
  var req = gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/civicinfo/v2/voterinfo',
    'params': {
      'electionId': electionId,
      'address': address
    }
  });
  req.execute(callback);
}
```

```html
<h1>Places To Vote</h1>
<p>Find a polling location near you.</p>
<div id="results"></div>
```

However, I'd like to have the user place their information in an input form and click a submit button. I can't seem to get the user input to go through my other functions once an input form is in place. Help? Please excuse my Frankenstein code.

```js
var userSubmitJS = document.querySelector('userSubmit');
var userInputJS = document.querySelector('userInput');
var address;
userSubmitJS.addEventListener('click', function()) {
  address = userInputJS.value;
  alert(address);
}

function lookup(address, callback) {
  var electionId;
  var req = gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/civicinfo/v2/voterinfo',
    'params': {
      'electionId': electionId,
      'address': address
    }
  });
  req.execute(callback);
}
```

```html
<h1>Places To Vote</h1>
<p>Find a polling location near you.</p>
<form>
  <input id="userInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter your address">
  <button type="submit" id="userSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Are you able to debug through console.log?

Comment: @SahuVKumar I'm not too familiar with using console log but any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I'm currently getting a "Failed to load resource: 400" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two errors in your code:

- if you want to get an element by ID, you need to pass `#` to `querySelector` (*e.g.* `#userSubmit` and `#userInput`)
- an "Uncaught `SyntaxError`" in your `addEventListener` (the position of the closing `)` was wrong)

To pass `address` to the `lookup` function, you can just call

```
lookup(address, my_callback)
```

where `my_callback` is the name of the [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).

```js
var userSubmitJS = document.querySelector('#userSubmit');
var userInputJS = document.querySelector('#userInput');
var address;
userSubmitJS.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  address = userInputJS.value;
  alert(address);
  lookup(address, my_callback);
});

function lookup(address, callback) {
  console.log('lookup');
  // ...
  callback();
}

function my_callback() {
  console.log('my_callback');
}
```

```html
<h1>Places To Vote</h1>
<p>Find a polling location near you.</p>
<form>
  <input id="userInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter your address">
  <button type="submit" id="userSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: You've addressed the typos (which we have a close reason for), but not the question, which is how to pass the information to the function.

Comment: Thank you for catching those errors! This fixed the alert, but I'm still not able to pass the address to my other functions. Any additional guidance would be greatly appreciated.